# Vuejs use slot variable inside parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Lets say we have a form component:

```
<!-- appform.vue -->
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <slot></slot>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</template>
```

And inside my app, i wanna use it and dynamically add formfields to it:

```
<!-- app.vue -->
<template>
    <appform>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    </appform>
</template>
```

Now I need to tell vuejs, that I wanna bind each input field, to the "model" variable of the datafield of the appform component.

```
<!-- app.vue -->
<template>
    <appform>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" :model="model.firstname" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" :model="model.lastname" />
    </appform>
</template>
```

Of course, this is not working, since vuejs says, that model is not inside the app datafield. How to tell it to use the "model" of the appform component and not from the current scope?

Comment: Can you please help me understand the purpose of appform component?

Comment: The appform should just encapsulate some default form behavior (set action, method, etc.). For demonstration purpose, I haven't included the logic to the post, since it is not necessary for my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

In `appform.vue`, expose `model` on the slot.

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <slot :model="model"></slot>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</template>
```

Then in `app.vue`, add a scoped template.

```
<template>
    <appform>
        <template v-slot="{model}">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" :model="model.firstname" />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" :model="model.lastname" />
        </template>
    </appform>
</template>
```

Also, on your input elements you are using `:model="model.firstname"`. This looks like an error to me. `input` elements do not have a `model` attribute. It's possible you meant to use `v-model="model.firstname"`.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am looking for. I read it in the docs, but my fault was, that I forgot to add '{' arround model.

Comment: @bernhardh All of the properties you add to the slot in `appform` are passed as a single object. The syntax, `slot-scope="{model}"` is actually destructuring that object (an es6 syntax). If you didn't destructure, say with `slot-scope="props"`, then the passed model property would be accessed as `props.model`.

Answer (score 2):

Since Vue 2.6.0, the `slot-scope` directive has been deprecated. The `v-slot` directive allows you to use scoped slots (and named ones as well):

```html
<template v-slot="{model}">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" :model="model.firstname" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" :model="model.lastname" />
</template>
```

Even though it doesn't produce an error, it looks like using `slot-scope` can silently fail without further notice.